# Design in mod_reqrite a rule from directory to file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to define following rewrite rule:

The user should enter a url to a directory like: [www.url.com/voucher](http://www.url.com/voucher)
But the real url should be: [www.url.com/voucher.php](http://www.url.com/voucher.php)
And the user should only see the first url - never the second.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this in .htaccess after **RewriteEngine on** line:

```
RewriteRule ^voucher /voucher.php
```

Comment: result is url.com/voucher.php/ in adressline.
Should be url.com/voucher/

Comment: Well, I was based in your initial specificacion:  www.url.com/voucher ->  www.url.com/voucher.php. If you were talking about www.url.com/voucher/ to www.url.com/voucher.php then the rewrite rule could be:
RewriteRule ^voucher/?$ /voucher.php

Comment: RewriteRule voucher voucher.php [L]

Got it with this. ty